# Цикл постоянный поиск

Tags: python

```
import requests

gettime = "20:00:00"

headers1 = {
    "Host": "xxxx.ru",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.82 Safari/537.36",
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Accept-Language": "ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
    "DNT": "1",
    "Referer": "http://xxxxxxx.ru/",
    "Cookie": "ASP.NET_SessionId=dsad242151251265; alertBrowser=1",
    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    "Connection": "keep-alive"
}

while True:
r = requests.post("http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", headers = headers1)
time = r.text[-21:-13]
print(time)
```

В переменной time появляется время в формате "00:00:00"
как сделать что бы он постоянно запрашивал время пока не будет "20:00:00" и дальше делал произвольное действие.

Comment: Сервер, который вы опрашиваете, сдохнет быстрее чем за 20 часов :Р

Comment: [DDOS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DoS-%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0#.D0.A0.D0.B0.D1.81.D0.BF.D1.80.D0.B5.D0.B4.D0.B5.D0.BB.D1.91.D0.BD.D0.BD.D0.B0.D1.8F_DoS-.D0.B0.D1.82.D0.B0.D0.BA.D0.B0) атаки гораздо эффективнее по сравнению с DOS атаками, поэтому есть смысл сразу писать [распределенное приложение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82) :-)

Comment: причем тут ддос? это автоматизация действий на сайте

Comment: типа этого 
while time = gettime:
print(time)
как сделать что бы он постоянно искал а не выполнялся один раз!

Comment: @Robocop если это для автоматизации, то можно воспользоваться кроном, чтобы в 20:00 часов каждый день скрипт запускать.

Comment: Время идет линейно?

Answer (score 1):

Часы идут с одной скоростью, поэтому достаточно запросить время один раз, сетевые запросы не идут мгновенно, поэтому милисекунды не учитываем.

Схема

1. Запрашиваем время на сервере
2. Находим разницу с нашим локальным
3. На основании разницы теперь знаем в какое время выполнить действие. К нашему времени на машине где запущен скрипт, прибавить нужное значение.
4. Проверяем время у себя, это быстрее и эффективнее. Когда оно наступит делаем что-то.

Comment: К сожалению не все так просто! время не соответствует никакому часовому поясу! хотя написано +3, оно может увеличится в самый важный момент! Поэтому нужно синхронизировать в реальном времени, и ждать, а как только появится то самое время которое нужно, произвести действие, например кликнуть

Comment: В любом случае не нужно дергать постоянно. Раз в 2-3 минуты если боитесь промазать будет достаточно. По описанию похоже что делаете бота, для них часто используют sikuli http://www.sikuli.org/ . Ставим проверку экрана, цифры совпали, нажали.

Comment: Если время линейно, то по архитектуре приложения, requests используем в виде отдельного самостоятельного скрипта, который пишет данные в файл. Дергаем его например по крону раз в какое-то время. Разнесение позволит править основной код не останавливая проверку и наоборот.

Comment: хочется самому изобрести! а не использовать готовое, плюс скрипт будет авторизовываться на сайте, подгружать файлы, и в конце синхронизировать время, а дальше производить действие!

Comment: можно и изобрести, будет интересно. Но постоянные запросы на чужой сервер могут быть заблокированы очень быстро, любой из систем защит, например в случае ddos атаки, подключают фильтр который заблокирует эти запросы по признаку. Если сервер свой, то вариант сокетов гораздо лучше подходит для данной задачи.